Python PySimpleGUIQt Combo "display with empty lines" error?
I try to a list of object for which I implement the __str__ method as asked by the documentation : https://docs.pysimplegui.com/en/latest/documentation/module/elements/combo/
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

class ComboPoint:
    def __init__(self, location) -> None:
        self.location = location
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "something"

when I call:
values_for_combo = [ComboPoint(location) for location in range(1,5)]
window[key_name_combo].update(values=values_for_combo)

I should except to have the same value displayed many time but I have only empty lines (which means that at least behind object is viewed).
Obviously, if I do :
values_for_combo = ["here we go" for location in range(1,5)]

that's work.
What I miss ?

maybe first use print() to check ComboPoint(location)  and to check values_for_combo. Maybe it needs to use str(ComboPoint(location)) to inform object that you want strings because list will not convert it automatically. And PYQt may not know that it is need to use str()

you wrote display error with empty lines - so where is this error? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

it would be simpler if you would create minimal reproducible example

I created code and it works when I use sg.Combo(values_for_combo) but not with window[key_name_combo].update(values=values_for_combo). But in PySimpleGUI work both versions. You may have to send information to author about problem.


PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.addItems(texts)
Parameters:
texts – list of strings


PySimpleGUI/tkinter can accept objects as values of widget, but PySimpleGUIQt/PySide cannot.

Source code when initiate a Combobox

items_as_strings = [str(v) for v in element.Values]
# element.QT_ComboBox.addItems(element.Values)
element.QT_ComboBox.addItems(items_as_strings)


Source code when update a Combobox

self.QT_ComboBox.addItems(values)

You can find that there's no code to converts values to a list of str in PySimpleGUIQt.py when update, so you need to do it by yourself at this moment.
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

class Point:
    def __init__(self, location) -> None:
        self.location = location

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Location {self.location}"

points = [Point(i) for i in range(5)]

window = sg.Window("Title", [[sg.Combo([0,1,2,3,4], key='COMBO')]], finalize=True)
window['COMBO'].update(values=tuple(map(str, points)))
window.read(close=True)


What you're saying seems logical, however I don't understand why put this in the official documentation if it's not the case :(
Thank you :)

why put this in the official documentation if it's not the case, not sure what you mean. Not everything perfect until now, so still something missed or wrong in the library.

@Draeli it seems JasonYang already send this problem to author(s): Question: PySide cannot accept a list of objects as the values for the Combobox element · Issue #6772 · PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI
